# Entity Framework creating link between two classes without unused duplication in domain model

Tags: entity-framework

I have been trying to create a many to many relationship without having to put unused properties within my view model using Entity Framework (MVC4 and EF5RC).

I have a `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And a `Role` class:

```
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<User> Users { get; set; }       
}
```

What I want to achieve is having a User that belongs to some roles (string names of roles at this point), they can be in multiple roles. Each role can have multiple users.

I do not want to have to put list of users in roles and list of roles in the users just so that Entity Framework is happy and will save it.

I have been trying to use the modelBuilder thing, (followed a few examples such as [Define relationships for hierarchical data in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935100/define-relationships-for-hierarchical-data-in-entity-framework-code-first) ).  With no joy.

The reason I want to avoid extra properties is it feels wrong to have null lists, or even worse lists of roles that then list other users. I would like my domain model to be clean and not have to bend to work with a repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use Entity Framework there is noo other choice than doing it in a way *that Entity Framework is happy*. But why should this be a point? I think in the first place you should focus on a domain model that simply works: it enforces business rules and it cooperates smoothly with EF.

Secondly, there is the choice: what do I expose? You can keep everything that involves EF (context + entities) internal to the assembly that contains the authorization logic. So you don't expose entity classes but dedicated classes (DTO's if you like). Your `User` could be such a class, because it does not expose other users in roles. Evidently, it is not a class that EF easily populates.

Your assembly should have a façade or service class that exposes some methods that offer just the data and activities that are needed for client code and nothing more. Internally it maps between entity classes and DTO's.

Recently, I have been working on an authorization library where I roughly followed these principles although, of course, there were some differences with your model.

Comment: the reason it is a point / issue for me is that the repository (a dumb data store) is now affecting the domain models.  Adding extra properties that are only required because of a repository smells a bit to me.  Saying that it is not the end of the world, but not as clean s I would like

Comment: I've worked with several ORM tools and never found one that gives total liberty to shape the domain the way you'd do if only the domain would matter. They all impose their own peculiarities upon the domain. I think EF does a pretty good job in minimizing its footprint (NHibernate better still), but yeah, it is present. So "if you can't beat them join them." Maybe you get closer to what you want with a many-to-many between `User` and `Role` without a `Users` collection in `Role`.

Comment: agreed @GertArnold, went with the extra properties in the end as ease of use. the rest of EF really speeds up development.